# How to prevent the application code from getting stuck in forever loop when using SerialFlash library in Arduino-Adafruit framework

Tags: c, adafruit, flash, feather, nrf52

I have been working on a project that runs on Adafruit's Bluefruit nRF52 board. I used the SerialFlash library for Arduino provided by Paul Stoffregen: https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/SerialFlash.The Flash chip used here is the Winbond 25Q128J. This library uses SPI protocol to communicate with the hardware flash memory connected to the Feather. The issue I'm facing is that sometimes (like 1 in 10 chance) during runtime, the code crashes and device gets reset due to watchdog trigger. I suspect this is due to the timer interrupt that I have set to trigger every 200us to generate a pulse wave and this interrupts the SPI's write functionality which the program calls in the main loop every 15 ms, causing some sort of race condition.

I observe that SerialFlash waits until the data is transmitted and received to/from the flash through SPI before leaving the subroutine and the timer interrupt setup in the code is causing invalid state (potentially race condition) and crashed the code. Is there a good way to debug this runtime error? Stepping through Debugger doesn't help since it introduces more timing issues.